# Swift - UITableView 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell'

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am working on a project for iOS in Swift. This app involves displaying JSON data in a UITableView.

I have the JSON Data parsed and all that but its not showing up on the tableview. When ever i run my app it gives me this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I am trying to do everything programmatically instead of using the storyboards. 
I will add my code below.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var postsCollection = [Post]()
    var service: PostService!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        service = PostService()
        service.getPosts
        {
            (response) in 
            self.loadPosts(response["Events"]! as! NSArray)
        }
    }  

    func loadPosts(events: NSArray)
    {
        for event in events
        {
            //var event = event["Events"]! as! NSDictionary
            print("\n-----------------------------------------------------")
            print("           RECEIVED_JSON_DATA")
            print("-----------------------------------------------------")
            print("Title              :   \(event["Title"])")
            print("Event Description  :   \(event["EventDescription"])")
            print("Event Location     :   \(event["EventLocation"])")
            print("Event StartTime    :   \(event["EventStartTime"])")
            print("Event EndTime      :   \(event["EventEndTime"])")
            print("RowKey             :   \(event["RowKey"])")
            print("-----------------------------------------------------\n")

            var title = event["Title"]! as! String
            var description = event["EventDescription"]! as! String
            var location = event["EventLocation"]! as! String
            var startTime = event["EventStartTime"]! as! String
            var endTime = event["EventEndTime"]! as! String
            //var eventURL = event["EventURL"]! as! String
            var rowKey = event["RowKey"]! as! String

            //var postObj = Post(title: title, description: description, location: location, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime, eventURL: eventURL, rowKey: rowKey)
            var postObj = Post(title: title, description: description, location: location, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime, rowKey: rowKey)

            postsCollection.append(postObj)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // TableView
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return postsCollection.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let object = postsCollection[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel!.text = object.title

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool 
    {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this and show me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Like i said, Im trying to do everything programmatically rather than using Storyboards. Is there any other way of doing it without using storyboards or xib?

Comment: Actually the error message tells you what to do: ***must register** a nib or **a class for the identifier***

Comment: When cell prototype is not added to the _tableView_ or _collectionView_ outlet in IB. One **must** register the cell Nib before dequeueing :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that somewhere (probably in `TableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`), you register the cell class:

Swift 4:

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Swift 3 and below:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is a better place for this when subclassin `UITableViewController`

Comment: Would this cause double-registering if an existing instance of `UITableViewController` had its view loaded again?

Comment: Well, I haven't seen a case when an existing instance had a view loaded again and as far as I know that would be a much more serious error, as that may lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

in viewDidLoad func and tell us the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `register` instead of `registerClass` in Swift 4.

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```